# Как получить имя переменной внутри функции

Tags: c#

Как можно получить имя передаваемой переменной в вызываемом методе?
Только передавать дополнительным параметром?
Может есть какой аналог `CallerMemberNameAttribute` только для получения имени передаваемой переменной?

На примере:

```
var variable = "some_value"; // имя переменной nameof(variable)
DoAction(variable);


public void DoAction(string value)
{
    var valueVariableName = ... // хочу получить имя переменной ("variable")
}
```

Буду благодарен за любые соображения.

---

Примечание: Изначально задумывалось сделать наподобие

```
public void DoAction(string value, [PreviousParameterName] string valueParameterName = null)
{
    var valueParameterName = ... // имя переменной (== "variable")
}
```

Но после уточнения вопроса [создания кастомных аттрибутов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753262/5598926) (отрабатывающих во время компиляции) стало ясно, что это сделать по-простому невозможно. Естественно, использовать рефлексию для решения данного вопроса нецелесообразно (может даже и не получилось бы, я не разбирался).

Comment: а зачем это может понадобиться? и нет, аналога нет

Comment: зачем вообще это может понадобиться?

Comment: Все сугубо для удобства разработки

Comment: а если вызывать `DoAction("some_value");` что вы ожидаете увидеть в таком случае?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper мне без разницы, хоть пусть эксепшн валится

Comment: @Grundy По поводу того, зачем может понадобится. Например, если хочется сделать статический метод, бросающий ArgumentNullException (вместо if (...) throw ...). Тогда в него достаточно передавать сам параметр, а не параметр с nameof(параметр). Господа, а за что минусы кидаете человеку?

Comment: Держи похожий вопрос на английском SO. Признанным считается ответ, что так нельзя. Однако есть и другие варианты. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121/finding-the-variable-name-passed-to-a-function

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко эти способы не совсем то, что мне нужно. Но спасибо :)

Comment: А что должно произойти, если в функцию будет передано выражение, содержащее несколько переменных? `DoAction(s1 + s2)`, например.

Comment: @VladD эксепшн например, мне не принципиально :)

Comment: @AGS17: Ну это как бы плохо: правильность вызова не видна на этапе компиляции. Хуже того, оптимизатор имеет обычно право убрать ненужную временную переменную, как ему это запретить?

Comment: @AGS17: Само понятие «переменная, которую передали в качестве аргумента», выглядит сомнительно на мой вкус. Аргументом функции является _выражение_, не _переменная_.

Comment: @VladD благодарю за разжевывание, необходимую информацию я для себя подчеркнул :)

Comment: @AGS17: Сам по себе _вопрос_ как раз очень хороший, не знаю, за что стоят минусы.

Comment: @VladD получение имени передаваемой переменной "для удобства разработки" выглядит как отладка через printf, за что и ставят минусы

Comment: @user270576: В [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685720/10105) вполне валидный юзкейс. Плюс вопрос по сути о теоретической возможности, то есть, об основах устройства CLR.

Comment: @VladD "Если вам имя переменной требуется не безусловно, а только в особых случаях с отладочными целями" - вполне валидный юзкейс? Debug brakepoint больше не работает? "Printf" в вызывающей функции будет иметь больше смысла и проще реализован. Формулировка вопроса заставляет думать, что речь идет не о теоретической возможности, а о костылях

Comment: @user270576: Разумеется, валидный. Например, если это числомолотилка, то conditional breakpoint _очень_ сильно замедляет пробег программы, так что вот такой вот код — вполне себе хороший костыль. Да, всё это можно сделать и прямее, за счёт большого ручной работы по логированию, но зачем? Кроме того: само знание фактажа о том, что имя поля или там название процедуры можно выцепить через рефлексию, а временной переменной — нет (или да, в некоторых случаях), является ни в коем случае не тривиальным.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В C# 8.0 завезут новый атрибут:

```
CallerArgumentExpression
```

С его помощью можно будет получить имя переменной, которое было передано.

Цитирую ответ, который мне дали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/903801/c-8-0-caller-argument-expression):

Если метод объявлен так:

```
public static class Debug
{
     public static void Assert(bool condition, [CallerArgumentExpression("condition")] string message = null);
}
```

и вызывается так:

```
Debug.Assert(someBoolean);
Debug.Assert(array != null);
Debug.Assert(array.Length == 1);
```

, то компилятор подставит значение второго аргумента:

```
Debug.Assert(someBoolean, "someBoolean");
Debug.Assert(array != null, "array != null");
Debug.Assert(array.Length == 1, "array.Length == 1");
```

Соответственно никаких просадок в производительности не будет, так как это будет делаться на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Да, видел, спасибо!

Answer (score 11):

Например, вот так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var world = "Hello, {0}!";
    DoAction(() => world);
}

static void DoAction(Expression<Func<string>> value)
{
    var me = (MemberExpression)value.Body;
    var variableName = me.Member.Name;
    var variableValue = value.Compile()();

    Console.WriteLine(variableValue, variableName);
}
```

**Но это будет работать медленно.** И точно так же будет медленно работать любая другая подобная "технология". Просто потому что уговорить компилятор сохранить имя переменной можно только превратив ее в поле или свойство - а способа быстро достать из объекта значение поля с неизвестным именем нет.

Comment: К сожалению, этот вариант чуть нарушает красоту моего класса. В моем случае логичнее уже напрямую `nameof()` передавать :) Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: +1, но вот мнение разработчиков языка: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1718037/#comment1596566_1718037

Answer (score 9):

Если вам имя переменной требуется не безусловно, а только в особых случаях с отладочными целями - то при наличии отладочных символов его можно попытаться достать из исходника.

Например, как-то вот так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string foobarbaz = null;
    Assert(foobarbaz != null);
    Assert(false);
    Assert(true && (false || new[] { true, false }[1]));
    Assert(false /* || true*/);
    Assert(
        false // || true
    );
    Assert /*trap*/ (false);
    Assert($"{{" == null);
}

[Conditional("DEBUG"), MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static void Assert(bool expression)
{
    if (expression) return;

    string expression_raw;
    var frame = new StackTrace(fNeedFileInfo: true).GetFrame(1);
    try
    {
        using (var file = File.OpenText(frame.GetFileName()))
        {
            for (int k = frame.GetFileLineNumber() - 1; k > 0; k--) file.ReadLine();
            for (int k = frame.GetFileColumnNumber() - 1; k > 0; k--) file.Read();

            var parser = new Parser(file);
            parser.Ensure(nameof(Assert));
            parser.ReadUntil('(');
            parser.Ensure("(");
            parser.BeginRecord();
            parser.ReadUntil(')');
            expression_raw = parser.EndRecord();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        expression_raw = "";
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Assertion {expression_raw.Trim()} failed at {frame.ToString()}");
}

private class Parser
{
    private readonly TextReader input;
    private StringBuilder output;
    private char current, prev;

    public Parser(TextReader input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void BeginRecord()
    {
        output = new StringBuilder();
    }
    public string EndRecord()
    {
        var result = output.ToString();
        output = null;
        return result;
    }

    private char Read()
    {
        var c = input.Read();
        if (c == -1) throw new EndOfStreamException();

        prev = current;
        current = (char)c;

        output?.Append(char.IsWhiteSpace(current) ? ' ' : current);
        return current;
    }

    public void Ensure(string v)
    {
        foreach (var c in v)
        {
            if (Read() != c) throw new IOException();
        }
    }

    public void ReadUntil(char end)
    {
        while (input.Peek() != end)
        {
            switch (Read())
            {
                case '(': ReadUntil(')'); Read(); break;
                case '[': ReadUntil(']'); Read(); break;
                case '{': ReadUntil('}'); Read(); break;
                case '\'': ReadCharacter(); if (Read() != '\'') throw new IOException(); break;
                case '"': ReadString(formattable: prev == '$'); Read(); break;

                case '/':
                    if (prev == '/')
                    {
                        do { Read(); } while (current != '\n' && current != '\r');
                    }
                    break;

                case '*':
                    if (prev == '/')
                    {
                        current = '\0';
                        do { Read(); } while (prev != '*' || current != '/');
                        current = '\0';
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReadCharacter()
    {
        if (Read() == '\\') Read();
    }

    private void ReadString(bool formattable)
    {
        while (input.Peek() != '"')
        {
            if (formattable && input.Peek() == '{')
            {
                Read();
                if (input.Peek() != '{')
                {
                    ReadUntil('}');
                }
                Read();
                continue;
            }

            ReadCharacter();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: День знатных извращений можно считать открытым. Я бы ещё добавил в `Assert` `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]`.

Comment: @VladD согласен, спасибо

Comment: @PavelMayorov благодарю за потраченное время, но думаю я уже понял, что мне максимально подходит использовать `nameof()` напрямую :) Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: А можно ловушки? `Assert /*trap*/ (false)` и `Assert($"{{" == null);`.

Comment: @VladD исправил

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ого, круто! Но всё же ещё: `Assert /*/ (trap)*/ (false);`

Comment: @VladD упс.....

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Вроде всё ещё не проходит? Надо по идее `prev != '*' || current != '/'`.

Comment: @VladD да, точно

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а нельзя для разбора апи roslyn как-то присобачить?

Comment: @Grundy наверное, как-то можно. Но я не разбирался

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Классно выходит :) Покамест я не смог завалить парсер, хотя честно старался.