# Почему AppDomain.CurrentDomain показывает такой путь?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nunit

В проекте Unit тестов использую AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, однако он выводит не то, что мне нужно. Вот путь, который находится в AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory:

```
C:\Users\User\source\repos\myproject\APR.AcceptanceTests\APR.AcceptanceTests.Suites\bin\x64\Debug\
```

Вот .cs файл, в котором вызываю AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот иерархия проектов тестов: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод, который вызывается из APR.AcceptanceTests.Suites

```
    public static void RecreateDatabase()
    {  
        var scriptsDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        CreateMySqlDatabase(scriptsDirectory);
    }
```

Мне нужен следующий путь: C:\Users\User\source\repos\myproject\APR.AcceptanceTests\APR.AcceptanceTests.**Core**\bin\x64\Debug\ 
а не
C:\Users\User\source\repos\myproject\APR.AcceptanceTests\APR.AcceptanceTests.**Suites**\bin\x64\Debug\

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory вызывается в ещё одном месте в проекте Core и там возвращает такой же путь.

Comment: а чем не устраивает текущий путь?

Comment: Мне нужен путь именно Core, потому что в нем есть папка с данными, к которой я хочу получить доступ

Comment: Настройте рабочий каталог, аппдомен берет путь оттуда

Comment: Возможно, вам просто достаточно будет поставить в core параметр copy to output directory = true?

Comment: Нет, это не работает

Comment: Не знаю, как это сделать напрямую, но можно с помощью регулярного выражения вырезать `APR.AcceptanceTests.Core` и вставить `APR.AcceptanceTests.Suites`.

Comment: Да, я делал так, но это, как-то костыльно, поэтому  и обратился сюда) (только наоборот - вырезать Suites и вставить Core)

Comment: @LevKostychenko, так как зависимые сборки копируются в выходную директорию найти их исходное положение проблематично

Comment: В таком случае лучшим решением будет перенести данные, доступ к которым я хочу получить через AppDomain, в Suites?

Comment: @LevKostychenko, а пробовал поставить нужной папке в свойствах _copy to output directory_?

Comment: Если сборка осуществляется с отладочной информацией, тогда можно попробовать получить адрес файла с текущим кодом и относительно его найти путь до нужной директории, но это совсем крайний случай, [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685720/186999)

Comment: На счет copy to output directory - немного не понимаю, про какие ты свойства говоришь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95708/discussion-between-grundy-and-lev-kostychenko).