# Как получить имена аргументов?

Tags: c#

Допустим есть следующий метод:

```
public static string GetLog(params object[] args)
{ ... }
```

Как внутри этого метода получить имена аргументов?
Т.е. при вызове

```
GetLog(user, fileName);
```

Он вернул "user, fileName".
Возможно ли на данный момент это?

Comment: При вызове функций Вы передаёте значения переменных, а не их имена. Вы же можете, например, вызывать вот так `GetLog(123, "hello");` - тут вообще имен переменных нет.

Comment: Но вы можете вызвать вот так `GetLog(nameof(variable));`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить имя переменной внутри функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685677/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: @tym32167 Да это понятно, я думал может я пропустил выход CallerArgumentExpression, но, видимо, нет